# In Biztalk mapper how to use split array concept

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

Required suggestion on below part.please any one give solution.

We have mapping from 850 to FlatFile

X12/PO1Loop1/PO1/PO109  and I need to map to field **VALUE** which is under record Option which is unbounded.

Split PO109 into substrings delimited by '.', foreach subsring after the first, create new Option with value=substring

So in input sample we have value like 147895632qwerqtyuui.789456123321456987

Similarly the field repeats under POLoop1.

So I need to split value based on (.) then pass a value to value field  under option record(unbounded).

I tried using below code snippet

```
public string SplitValues(string strValue)
{

string[] arrValue = strValue.Split(".".ToCharArray());  
 foreach (string strDisplay in arrValue)  
 {
return strDisplay; 
}

}
```

But it doesn't works, and  I am not really familiar with the String methods and I am not sure if there's an easy way to do this. I have a String which contains couple of values delimited with "." .

So I need to separate values based on delimiter(.) and pass value to field.

How can I do this

Comment: The question is quite unclear, are you trying to map each of the split value into multiple nodes in the output schema, such as `"11.12"` -> `[11, 12]` and the output is something like `<option>11</option>` and `<option>12</option>`?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, not too clear what is your objective, but I think you want to split a node that has some kind of delimiter into multiple nodes... if so, Try this: https://seroter.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/splitting-delimited-values-in-biztalk-maps/

He is doing exactly that.  Given a node with `a|b|c|d` as value, output multiple nodes, each containing the value after splitted by `|`, so node1 = a, node2 = b, node3 = c, node4 = d.